# C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' was matched - can't resolve this.

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std; 
#include "bcio2.h"

int error, x;
char totalimpulse[80], averageimpulse[80], ejection[50], emptymass[50], enginemass[50], fuelmass[50];
char launch[50];
void validate_number();

int main(void)
{
    clrscr();
    do{
        printf("\nTotal Impulse delivered: ");
        gets(totalimpulse);
        validate_number();
    } while (error != 0);

    do{
        printf("\nAverage Impulse delivered: ");
        gets(averageimpulse);
        validate_number();
    } while (error != 0);

    do{
        printf("\nTime that ejection charge fires: ");
        gets(ejection);
        validate_number();
    } while (error != 0);

    do{
        printf("\nThe mass of the empty vehicle: ");
        gets(emptymass);
        validate_number();
    } while (error != 0);

    do{
        printf("\nThe mass of the engine: ");
        gets(enginemass);
        validate_number();
    } while (error != 0);

    do{
        printf("\nThe mass of fuel: ");
        gets(fuelmass);
        validate_number();
    } while (error != 0);

printf("\nRocket parameters entered: \n");
   printf("\nTotal Impulse delivered: %s\n", totalimpulse);
   printf("Average Impulse delivered: %s\n", averageimpulse);
   printf("Time that ejection charge fires: %s\n", ejection);
   printf("The mass of the empty vehicle: %sg\n", emptymass);
   printf("The mass of the engine: %sg\n", enginemass);
   printf("The mass of fuel: %sg\n", fuelmass);

char ans;
do
{
       cout<< "\nLaunch simulation? (Y/N) : \n";
       cout<< "You must type a 'Y' or an 'N'.\n";
       cin >> ans;
}
while((ans !='Y')&&(ans !='N')&&(ans !='y')&&(ans !='n'));

if (ans == 'N')
    {
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
    else if (ans == 'Y')
    {
        // do something, calculations display page
        return 0;
    }
}

   /************ Test all input in range 0 to 9 ****************/
   void validate_number()
   {
       int errange = 0, numonly = 0, errlength = 0;
       /********* validate numbers ********/
       error = 0;

       for (x = 0; x<strlen(totalimpulse); x++){

           if (totalimpulse[x] >= '0' && totalimpulse[x] <= '9');    else{
               numonly++;
               error++;
           }

       for (x = 0; x<strlen(averageimpulse); x++){

           if (averageimpulse[x] >= '0' && averageimpulse[x] <= '9');    else{
               numonly++;
               error++;
           }

       for (x = 0; x<strlen(ejection); x++){

           if (ejection[x] >= '0' && ejection[x] <= '9');    else{
               numonly++;
               error++;
           }

       for (x = 0; x<strlen(emptymass); x++){

           if (emptymass[x] >= '0' && emptymass[x] <= '9');    else{
               numonly++;
               error++;
           }

       for (x = 0; x<strlen(enginemass); x++){

           if (enginemass[x] >= '0' && enginemass[x] <= '9');    else{
               numonly++;
               error++;
           }

       for (x = 0; x<strlen(fuelmass); x++){

           if (fuelmass[x] >= '0' && fuelmass[x] <= '9');    else{
               numonly++;
               error++;
           }
       }
       /********* validate range ********/
       if (strlen(totalimpulse) <= 3){
           x = atoi(totalimpulse);

           if (x >= 0 && x <= 256)
               ;
           else{
               errange++;
               error++;
           }
       }
       else{
           errlength++;
           error++;
       }


       /**************** Report errors ******************/
       if (error != 0){
           if (numonly>0)
               printf("\nOnly values in the range 0 to 9 are valid ");
           if (errange>0)
               printf("\nValue must be in the range 0 to 255");
           if (errlength>0)
               printf("\nMore than three values were entered");
       }
```

I've counted 21 open braces and 21 closed braces which all seem to be positioned correctly yet I'm still getting the error, anything a fresh pair of eyes can help me with? I've counted the brackets so many times over that I'm going crazy.

It's a basic error for a basic problem but I'm just clueless as to what to change or add.

Comment: You don't have a brace at the end of the last function.

Comment: Get a good IDE. Your ; are all over the shop eg `if (ans == 'N')
    {
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
    else if (ans == 'Y')
    {
        // do something, calculations display page
        return 0;
    }
}
'

Comment: The first `for` loop in `validate_number()` definitely looks fishy. As it is, all next code is 'inside' that for-loop.

Comment: Actually, you also have a bunch of unclosed for-loops, an extra closing brace after an if statement, and probably other errors as well. Seriously, it is not hard to find syntax errors in this code. Have you considered using consistent indentation, and replacing single-line control flow statements with blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 27 open braces in the code.

```
[11:05am][wlynch@watermelon ~] fgrep -o '{' /tmp/asd.cc | wc -l
      27
[11:05am][wlynch@watermelon ~] fgrep -o '}' /tmp/asd.cc | wc -l
      21
```

Notably, there are two open braces in this piece of code, but only 1 closing brace:

```
   for (x = 0; x<strlen(totalimpulse); x++){

       if (totalimpulse[x] >= '0' && totalimpulse[x] <= '9');    else{
           numonly++;
           error++;
       }
```

Additionally, this isn't invalid, but is awfully written:

```
if (averageimpulse[x] >= '0' && averageimpulse[x] <= '9');    else{
```

Please write it as:

```
if (not (averageimpulse[x] >= '0' && averageimpulse[x] <= '9')) {
```

or:

```
if (averageimpulse[x] < '0' || averageimpulse[x] > '9')) {
```